# Почему QSettings перестал сохранять текст в info1?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qsettings

Я реализовал передачу данных посредством сигнала из класса `AnotherWindow` в класс `MainWindow`, то есть `info1` отправляет текст в `Info4` все работает как нужно, но `QSettings` перестали хранить текст в `info1` после закрытия `MainWindow` и это только такая проблема в `info1`.

Я думаю, проблема в функции `show_AnotherWindow()`. 
Окно `AnotherWindow` открывается при нажатии мышкой на слово **`Данные`**. 
Я был бы благодарен за совет.

```py
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.message_a = ' '

        self.saveSettingValues()

        try:
            self.move(self.settings_windows.value('window position'))
        except:
            pass

        self.l_place_value = self.settings_Text.value('place')
        self.l_place = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_place.setText(self.l_place_value)
        self.l_date = qtw.QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.l_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.l_date.setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy р.")
        self.l_date.setDate(qtc.QDate.currentDate())
        self.l_date.calendarWidget()
        self.l_recipient = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_address = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_case_number = qtw.QLineEdit(self)

        form_layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout)
        self.label_1 = qtw.QLabel(text=self.message_a)
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout.addRow(self.label_1)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_place)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_date)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_recipient)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_address)
        form_layout.addRow("Info4", self.l_case_number)
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        self.label_2 = qtw.QLabel(self.tr("Данные*"))
        form_layout.addRow(self.label_2)

        self.label_2.mouseReleaseEvent = self.showText1

        push_btn_close = qtw.QPushButton("Закрыть", self)
        push_btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        push_btn_close.move(353, 260)
        push_btn_close.resize(100, 26)

    # функция  сохранение данных
    def saveSettingValues(self):
        self.settings_windows = QSettings('MyApp', 'Win location')
        self.settings_Text = QSettings('MyApp', 'text')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings_windows.setValue('window position', self.pos())
        self.settings_Text.setValue('place', self.l_place.text())

    def showText1(self, event):
        self.show_AnotherWindow()

    @qtc.pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_messages(self, message_a):  # функция отправки текста до Info4
        self.message_a = message_a

        self.l_case_number.setText(self.message_a)

    def show_AnotherWindow(self):
        self.dialog = AnotherWindow()
        self.dialog.set_messages(self.message_a)
        self.dialog.submitted.connect(self.update_messages)
        self.dialog.show()

class AnotherWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    submitted = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.saveSettingTab()

        self.setWindowTitle(" ")
        self.setFixedSize(350, 200)

        self.l_recipient_name_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value('recipient name')
        self.l_recipient_name = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_name.setText(self.l_recipient_name_value)

        self.l_recipient_mobil_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value('recipient mobil')
        self.l_recipient_mobil = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_mobil.setText(self.l_recipient_mobil_value)

        self.l_recipient_address_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value('recipient address')
        self.l_recipient_address = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_address.setText(self.l_recipient_address_value)

        form_layout2 = qtw.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout2)
        form_layout2.addRow("info1", self.l_recipient_name)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout2.addRow("info2", self.l_recipient_mobil)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout2.addRow("info3", self.l_recipient_address)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())

        self.push_btn = qtw.QPushButton("OK", self)
        self.push_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_submit)
        self.push_btn.move(10, 140)
        self.push_btn.resize(100, 26)

    def set_messages(self, message_a):   # функция отправки текста начало
        self.l_recipient_name.setText(message_a)

    def on_submit(self):
        self.submitted.emit(self.l_recipient_name.text())

    def saveSettingTab(self):
        self.settings_wintable_text = qtc.QSettings('MyApp3', 'text')   # функция  сохранение данных

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue('recipient name', self.l_recipient_name.text())
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue('recipient mobil', self.l_recipient_mobil.text())
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue('recipient address', self.l_recipient_address.text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSettings` **не** перестали хранить текст в `info1` после закрытия `MainWindow`.

Вы просто вызовом `self.dialog.set_messages(self.message_a)` переписываете его помещая туда **`пробел`**, т.к.  у вас в конструкторе `self.message_a = ' '`

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings


class AnotherWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    submitted = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.saveSettingTab()

        self.setWindowTitle(" ")
        self.setFixedSize(350, 200)

        self.l_recipient_name_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value(
            'recipient name')
        self.l_recipient_name = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_name.setText(self.l_recipient_name_value)

        self.l_recipient_mobil_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value(
            'recipient mobil')
        self.l_recipient_mobil = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_mobil.setText(self.l_recipient_mobil_value)

        self.l_recipient_address_value = self.settings_wintable_text.value(
            'recipient address')
        self.l_recipient_address = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_recipient_address.setText(self.l_recipient_address_value)

        form_layout2 = qtw.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout2)
        form_layout2.addRow("info1", self.l_recipient_name)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout2.addRow("info2", self.l_recipient_mobil)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout2.addRow("info3", self.l_recipient_address)
        form_layout2.addRow(qtw.QLabel())

        self.push_btn = qtw.QPushButton("OK", self)
        self.push_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_submit)
        self.push_btn.move(10, 140)
        self.push_btn.resize(100, 26)

    # функция отправки текста начало
    def set_messages(self, message_a):            
        self.l_recipient_name.setText(message_a)

    def on_submit(self):
        self.submitted.emit(self.l_recipient_name.text())

    def saveSettingTab(self):
        # функция  сохранение данных
        self.settings_wintable_text = qtc.QSettings('MyApp3', 'text') 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue(
            'recipient name', self.l_recipient_name.text())
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue(
            'recipient mobil', self.l_recipient_mobil.text())
        self.settings_wintable_text.setValue(
            'recipient address', self.l_recipient_address.text())
  

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.message_a = ' '                                           # ???

        self.saveSettingValues()

        try:
            self.move(self.settings_windows.value('window position'))
        except:
            pass

        self.l_place_value = self.settings_Text.value('place')
        print(f'self.l_place_value = {self.l_place_value}') #
        self.l_place = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_place.setText(self.l_place_value)
        
        self.l_date = qtw.QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.l_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.l_date.setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy р.")
        self.l_date.setDate(qtc.QDate.currentDate())
        self.l_date.calendarWidget()
        
        self.l_recipient = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_address = qtw.QLineEdit(self)
        self.l_case_number = qtw.QLineEdit(self)

        form_layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(form_layout)
        
        self.label_1 = qtw.QLabel(text=self.message_a)                 # ???
        
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        form_layout.addRow(self.label_1)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_place)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_date)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_recipient)
        form_layout.addRow(" ", self.l_address)
        form_layout.addRow("Info4", self.l_case_number)
        form_layout.addRow(qtw.QLabel())
        self.label_2 = qtw.QLabel(self.tr("Данные*"))
        form_layout.addRow(self.label_2)

        self.label_2.mouseReleaseEvent = self.showText1

        push_btn_close = qtw.QPushButton("Закрыть", self)
        push_btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        push_btn_close.move(353, 260)
        push_btn_close.resize(100, 26)

    # функция  сохранение данных
    def saveSettingValues(self):
        self.settings_windows = QSettings('MyApp', 'Win location')
        self.settings_Text = QSettings('MyApp', 'text')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings_windows.setValue('window position', self.pos())
        self.settings_Text.setValue('place', self.l_place.text())

    def showText1(self, event):
        self.show_AnotherWindow()

    @qtc.pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_messages(self, message_a):  # функция отправки текста до Info4
        self.message_a = message_a
        self.l_case_number.setText(self.message_a)

    def show_AnotherWindow(self):
        self.dialog = AnotherWindow()               
        
#        self.dialog.set_messages(self.message_a)                      # ???

        self.dialog.submitted.connect(self.update_messages)
        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет ! СПС!....